MAX TOTAL SUPPLY ON ETHERSCAN IS 0
I deployed my token to MetaMask and it did not reflect the token name or the decimal. I manually had to input it. After I deployed to etherscan it is showing MAX TOTAL SUPPLY: 0 HOLDERS 0 TOTAL TRANSFERS 0. I am deploying on sepolia testnet. I am completely new to this so I'm lost. Go easy on me. Below is my solidity contract
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Capped.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "./MultiSigWallet.sol";

contract GNairaToken is ERC20, ERC20Capped, ERC20Burnable {
    address payable public owner;
    uint256 public blockReward;

    constructor(
        uint256 cap,
        uint256 reward
    ) ERC20("GNairaToken", "gNGN") ERC20Capped(cap) {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        _mint(owner, cap);
        blockReward = reward;
    }

    function _update(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 value
    ) internal virtual override(ERC20, ERC20Capped) {
        super._update(from, to, value);
        if (from == address(0)) {
            uint256 maxSupply = cap();
            uint256 supply = totalSupply();
            if (supply > maxSupply) {
                revert ERC20ExceededCap(supply, maxSupply);
            }
        }
    }

    function _mintMinerReward() internal {
        _mint(block.coinbase, blockReward);
    }

    function setBlockReward(uint256 reward) public onlyOwner {
        blockReward = reward * 10 ** decimals();
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 value
    ) internal virtual {
        if (
            from != address(0) &&
            to != block.coinbase &&
            block.coinbase != address(0)
        ) {
            _mintMinerReward();
        }
        super._update(from, to, value);
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can call this function!");
        _;
    }
}

Now when I deploy with hardhat from my vsCode it shows: 
Deploying contracts with the account: 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266 
GNairaToken deployed to: 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 
Total Supply: 10000000.0 
Deployer's token balance: 10000000.0 
Deployment successful 
Total Supply: 10000000.0 
Why is it different on the Etherscans link

Hm, you wouldn't be deploying to etherscan or to metamask, but to sepolia. As metamask doesn't know anything about your token you'd have to manually input the information. Etherscan is scraping on chain data, and so may or may not track information. To be sure you'd query totalSupply()  at your contracts address directly. Can do programmatically, use a tool like https://tenderly.co, or verify the contract and explicitly call via etherscans read tab at your contract. However I don't see contract data at that address, instead 62 eth and 20k transfers. Can you please paste the transaction hash.

Is it deployed to the correct network? Looking at the address it shows as a phishing scam on etherscan.io.
